# Отправка POST на сервер

Tags: c#, node.js, post

Нужно отправить POST-запрос на сервер, который должен отправляться с ключом `data`. Сделал так:

```
      using (var webClient = new WebClient())
{
      var pars = new NameValueCollection();
      pars.Add("data", "something");
      var response = webClient.UploadValues(URL, pars);
}
```

Но сервер Node.js выдает ошибку: `Cannot read property 'data' of undefined`. Данные же берутся из `request.body.data`.

Где может быть проблема?

Comment: Какой фреймворк на сервере?

Comment: Прошу прощения за столь долгий ответ. На сервере используется Express.

Comment: Используйте https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser

Comment: Спасибо, это действительно помогло. Если есть желание, то напишите свое сообщение в качестве ответа.